# Make BooleanField required in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've got a model with a boolean field that I'd like to deserialize with the Django rest framework and I want the serializer to complain when a field is missing in the post request. Yet, it doesn't. It silently interprets a missing boolean as False.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """
     Message between two users
"""
     user = models.OneToOneField(User, verbose_name="django authentication user", related_name='user_profile')
     newsletter = models.BooleanField(null=False)
     research = models.BooleanField(null=False)
```

The model is created with a Serialiser like this:

```
 class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 research = BooleanField(source='research', required=True)
 newsletter = BooleanField(source='newsletter', required=True)

 class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ('research', 'newsletter')
```

In my view I'm also creating a user, so I have some manual steps:

```
 def post(self, request, format=None):
    userprofile_serializer = UserProfileSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    reg_serializer = RegistrationSerializer(data=request.DATA)
    phone_serializer = PhoneSerializer(data=request.DATA)


    errors = {}
    if userprofile_serializer.is_valid() and reg_serializer.is_valid() and phone_serializer.is_valid():
        user = reg_serializer.save()
        data = reg_serializer.data

        user_profile = userprofile_serializer.object
        user_profile.user = user
        userprofile_serializer.save()

        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    errors.update(reg_serializer.errors)
    # ...
    return Response(errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

However, the following test case fails, because the rest framework doesn't complain about the missing param but instead inserts a False in from_native

```
     def test_error_missing_flag(self):
    data = {'username': "test", 'password': "123test", 'email': 'test@me.com',
            'newsletter': 'true', 'uuid': self.uuid}

    response = self.client.post(reverse('app_register'), data)
    # should complain that 'research' is not found
    self.assertTrue('research' in response.data)
```

If I replace my 'research' field with an Integer field that the serializer fails as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an issue with Boolean fields and the `required` argument.  Should now be fixed in master.

See this issue: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1004

Comment: Thanks. Was just debugging it and found the default value, too. How stable is the master? Can I pull this for production?

Comment: If you pin against a specific commit, then life should be good.  Don't just track master tho - the next version is planned as 2.4.0, which means bits of API will move through the deprecation process.  That's pretty strict, but you wouldn't want to just upgrade to it without realising.

Comment: Cheers. For now I stick with 2.3.7 but overwrote BooleanField like this: `class NonDefaultBooleanField(BooleanField):
    default = None`

Comment: Hi, I'm using DRF 3.1.1 and this still seems to be an issue unless I use serializers.NullBooleanField().  Ie, using serializers.BooleanField with "required=True" if the field is not submitted to the serialiser no error is raised.

Answer (score 2):

Add

```
your_field = serializers.NullBooleanField(required=False)
```

in `serializer`.

That's it. It'll work :)

Comment: i think you can also add serializers.BooleanField(required=False, allow_null=True)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new custom class:

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class RequirableBooleanField(serializers.BooleanField):
    default_empty_html = serializers.empty
```

Now, you can use:

```py
research = RequirableBooleanField(required=True)
```

or

```py
research = RequirableBooleanField(required=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who has read @Tom's accepted answer from 2013 and finds that this still doesn't work, it's because this behavior is intended for HTML form inputs. Here's the [original issue](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/1004).

To use `serializers.BooleanField` with a JSON payload, convert your `request.POST` to a Python `dict` by doing `request.POST.dict()` and pass it to your serializer while initializing.