# How to stop DRF's ModelSerializer to use model field's default value?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm stucked with this strange bug(?) with BooleanField. While partial_update, serializer is always set all boolean values to false, if it is not set in request.

My models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    agree_email = BooleanField(blank=True)
    agree_sms = BooleanField(blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserChangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = "first_name", "agree_email", "agree_sms"
```

When i trying to set `agree_email` to True - it's validating as `{'agree_email': True, 'agree_sms': False}`, and if i try to set `agree_sms` to true - it'll validate it as `{'agree_email': False, 'agree_sms': True}` and update User object respectively.

How to prevent such behavior of DRF?

Comment: i think this will work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59100606/12201407
if works let me know. I'll add it as answer so that you can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can set current value as default value when request data does not have the field.

```py
class UserChangeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AZUser
        fields = ("first_name", "agree_email", "agree_sms")
    def validate(self, attrs):
        if self.instance:
            attrs["agree_mail"] = attrs.get("agree_mail", self.instance.agree_mail)
            attrs["agree_sms"] = attrs.get("agree_sms", self.instance.agree_sms)
        return attrs
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about it, but I thought that there might be another option.

Comment: UPD: looks like it was a DRF bug, because it no longer set fields to default value after validation after i updated it